# How to put a heatmap in ngx-leaflet?

Tags: angular, typescript, leaflet, heatmap, ngx-leaflet

I would like to put a heatmap over a ngx-leaflet map (using angular), like in the following image.

How can I achieve that?

[image]

Here is the [demo](http://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.heat/demo) of the example.

Comment: the bsd-2 license prohibits me using it in my case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Install leaflet, ngx-leaflet, @types/leaflet

```
npm install leaflet
npm install leaflet.heat
npm install @asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet
npm install --save-dev @types/leaflet
```

Import leaflet.css in angular.json

```
  "styles": ["../node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css", "styles.css"]
```

Install Leaflet.heat & import it on comp.ts, import the geographic data to be used from assets

```
import 'leaflet.heat/dist/leaflet-heat.js'
import { addressPoints } from '../assets/realworld.10000'
```

Listen to onMapReady event get the reference to the map & add heatmap to the map

```
onMapReady(map) {
    let newAddressPoints = addressPoints.map(function (p) { return [p[0], p[1]]; });
    const heat = L.heatLayer(newAddressPoints).addTo(map);
}
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/jn11pwkxw)

Comment: This was necessary as well: `npm install leaflet.heat`. Thank you.

Comment: Not to mention...    `npm i @types/leaflet.heat`