# leaflet.heat not working for Angular 12-14

Tags: angular, leaflet, heatmap

I am having issues getting leaflet.heat to work in Angular 12-14. Leaflet basic map displays, however, the heatmap will not display over the map.

I am following the thread from:
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54858755/how-to-put-a-heatmap-in-ngx-leaflet)

which provides a working version, however, it is using Angular 7 in the demo:
[Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/jn11pwkxw)

I have attempted to recreate the demo on my own machine, Angular 14, and using Angular 12 in Code Sandbox

My heatmap failing to display Code Sandbox demo: [Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/leaflet-heat-angular-12-r2rt1o?file=/src/app/app.component.ts)

There were some errors being triggered in the Angular 7 Code Sandbox working demo version related to const heat. I was able to fix them with (L as any) and also adding the parameter { radius: 25 } to heatLayer, but I am at a loss of what else to do to get the heatmap to work at this point.

Is leaflet.heat just incompatible with newer versions of Angular? if so, is there a Leaflet heatmap libary that anyone could recommend?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just import `import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css'` and the codesandbox works as expected

[image]

I am sure that it will work if you upgrade also in angular 14.x